# Nextjs Image adds a second ? question mark to image url

Tags: next.js, query-string, nextjs-image

if image url already have a query string like this:

```
domain.com/image?id=1234
```

nextjs Image adds query parameters with an additional question mark. like:

```
domain.com/image?id=1234?format=jpg&width=768
```

any idea how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a stackblitz based on the ask above via the documentation - when using url querystrings both on an internal image that is in the `_public` directory or an external image from a url, I could not replicate the issue

https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-lhjx2o?file=pages/index.js

Review line 5 and 114.

Is it possible there is some other rewriting happening on your hosted webserver?